# unable to access Werkzeug server running in vagrant machine from the host machine

Tags: vagrant

I created a vagrant machine. Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
    sudo pip3 install flask
  SHELL
end
```

everything works fine inside the virtual machine. Running the following app works fine inside the virtual machine.
basic.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({"message": "Hello World"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

[Result of running basic.py inside the virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a1cp.png)

But trying to access the server from the host machine (via chrome browser) gives the message below:
[unable to access the server from the host machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfjF.png)

[trying to reload the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzA7m.png)

I tried to disable my antivirus (Norton just to check if Norton is filtering and blocking ports) but I have the same result. Did anyone else experience the same issue? Can someone help figure out what's wrong then how to fix it?

@Mirko Ebert, Trying to reach the server via "curl -v localhost:5000" gives the response below:
from inside the VM:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ curl -v localhost:5000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to ::1 port 5000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 31
< Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.6.7
< Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 21:15:45 GMT
<
{
  "message": "Hello World"
}
* Closing connection 0
```

From the host machine:

```
$ curl -v localhost:5000
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*
  Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.62.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection was reset
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

Comment: Can you try to reach the server via Curl (curl -v localhost:500) and post the response here.

Comment: Hello Mirko Ebert thanks for trying to help me, I've just posted the response you asked me

Comment: If you got a connect reset, it looks like a firewall. Do use any firewall protection?

Comment: I use Norton antivirus which has a firewall. I tried to disable the its firewall and the auto-protection for one hour but I got : "Connection was aborted"